# trying to derive a new column using a previous column?

Tags: ssis, flat-file

I have a Item, Warehouse, and Qty but the new requirement is to take Item and the last two digits of warehouse and add a one before that so that gives us the item + plant number. I am reading the flat file and deriving these three columns but i am new to using an expression that would give me the last two digits of warehouse and add a 1. For example 513 is the warehouse so the result would be 113. Any Help with this would be really appreciated. What i tried so far:

```
Item  +  1  +  SUBSTRING( "WareHouse",2,2 )
```

Comment: I think the starting point would be this link for [Derived Column Task](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/211/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-data-flow/). In the `Derived Column Transformation Editor` you should be able to use your logic to derived your new column.

Comment: @t_m i did all the things in the article already i had the entire package setup and running already but the new requirement was to add a new column called item + plant and the plant is derived from warehouse by taking the last two digits and adding a 1 before it. we are going to use the item+plant as a new primary key. so i know using the substring(warehouse,2,2) will give me the last two then i tried to add a 1 + substring and before all that add the item. I haven't used the expression before.

Comment: As I understand you need your expression modified to `[Item] + "1" + SUBSTRING([Warehouse], 2,2)`

Comment: @t_m Thanks that fixed my issue, now i have another issue ITEM + PLANT 0009PC      110     There are spaces in between ITEM and PLANT and TRIM doesn't eliminate the empty spaces, it only takes care of the characters in ITEM and WareHouse, so how does one delete the empty spaces.

Comment: use `REPLACE` function to remove all empty spaces if this is what you require.

Comment: @t_m thanks i did a trim on the item, inside the main trim and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my issue:

```
Item + LTRIM("1" + LTRIM(SUBSTRING(WareHouse,2,2)))
```